# Interactable Objects Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all, I'm sorry about the lack of information in the title. but I couldn't do better.
The point is I builded an abstract class who checks all my collisions, inside there is a public bool called "isInteracting" to check if I'm inside a collider, if I do "isInteracting" is true, otherwise false. So, classes who inherits from this parent class can use "isInteracting" to knows when I'm inside the collider an do something (ex. display a message, play a sound, etc.), when I created the second class who inherits from the parent class I realized my bool to check if I'm inside the collider didn't work fine because both child classes call it, How can I fix it? make them independents.

Simple Example:

```
public class Waitress : CollisionBehaviour
{
    public override void SayHi()
    {
        if (isInteracting) Debug.Log("Hi");
        else return;
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        SayHi();
        base.Update();
    }
}
```

"SayHi()" is an abstract method from the abstract class "CollisionBehaviour", and "Update()" is overridden because it's virtual.

At the request of @Poul Bak:

Parent Class:

```
public abstract class CollisionBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] public bool isInteractingByButtonAction;
    [HideInInspector] public bool isInteractingByTriggerCollision;
    private bool buttonPressed, isInside, a, b;

    private void CheckStay()
    {
        isInteractingByTriggerCollision = true;

        // GameInputs.Interact is a mapped button from my controller
        if (GameInputs.Interact && !buttonPressed)
        {
            buttonPressed = true;
            isInteractingByButtonAction = true;
        }

        a = (!buttonPressed) ? true : false;
        b = (!buttonPressed) ? true : false;
    }

    private void CheckExit()
    {
        isInside = false;
        b = false;
        isInteractingByButtonAction = false;
        isInteractingByTriggerCollision = false;

        if (buttonPressed) buttonPressed = false;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
       if (other.CompareTag("Player")) isInside = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        CheckExit();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isInside) CheckStay();
    }

    public virtual void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (a && b) { /* Will display a sprite to indicate which button should be pressed*/ }
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class InteractableObject : CollisionBehaviour
{
    #region Exposed Variables

    public AnimationCurve ease;
    public float smoothTime;
    public float minFov = 30;
    public float maxFov = 50;
    #endregion

    private float currentVelocity;

    private void InteractionFieldOfView()
    {
        // Animerp is an animation curve interpolation... Clever name I know
        Camera.main.fieldOfView = isInteractingByTriggerCollision.Animerp(maxFov, minFov, ref currentVelocity, smoothTime, ease);
    }

    public override void LateUpdate()
    {
        InteractionFieldOfView();
        base.LateUpdate();
    }
}
```

Well, camera field of view (isInteractingByTriggerCollision) only works fine when only one class inherit from CollisionBehaviour, as I told you.
BTW, I avoid OntriggerStay because garbage collector is pretty high

Comment: Please show the code that sets isInteracting and other important stuff.

Comment: @PoulBak sorry for the late reply, I was busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post is **poorly formatted and explained** and I found it hard to understand what you want your code to do an the errors being faced, nevertheless I took a shot.

This class should replace your `CollisionBehaviour` class, it essentially imitates `OnTriggerStay` by calling a function every frame while the player is within the trigger.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SphereCollider))]
internal abstract class CollisionTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool _isPlayerInsideTrigger = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(_isPlayerInsideTrigger)
        {
            FakeOnTriggerStay();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if(!collider.CompareTag("Player")) return;
        _isPlayerInsideTrigger = true;
    }

    public abstract void FakeOnTriggerStay();

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider)
    {
        if(!collider.CompareTag("Player")) return;
        _isPlayerInsideTrigger = false;
    }
}
```

This is an example to demonstrate what your `Waitress` class would look like using the provided class above.

```
internal class Waitress : CollisionTrigger
{
    public override void FakeOnTriggerStay()
    {
        // Replace this with input system you are using.
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(...))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know, I had to clean a lot to make it was "easy" to understand, About the "Waitress" class, it was just an example, quite simple. I like what you did, but it's not exactly what I need, what I want is avoid use repetitive patterns each time I create a new class, this is why I made a class who checks when I'm collide with something and return me a bool if indeed it's. but this bool is the same for every child class, and every class change his value, so I can't to check if I'm collide with something, because I'm not collide with all these objects at the same time.

Comment: The `CollisionTrigger` class will check if the player is colliding with something and if it is will call the `FakeOnTriggerStay` method. It should do exactly what you intend it to do. The boolean variables are unneeded with this cleaner polymorphic approach, please try my code and tell me if it doesn't work first. Thank you.

Comment: Well it works like a charm, I need to Implement the rest of my code with this structure now, but I've got a question, why did you choose internal? I read about internal before, but I dont know how it works exactly. And thanks of course.

Comment: The keyword `internal` is implicitly used if you don't state the access modifier (i.e. `public`). In my personal projects, I tend to use `internal` as most classes don't need to be `public`. The `internal` accessor means that outside of the same assembly (i.e. a dll) it cannot be accessed (read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)), it's useful when creating an API library.